# JavaScript: FQDN regexp doesn't validate long names

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regexp that validates a string to be an FQDN:

```
var fqdnRegExp = new RegExp("^([a-z0-9]+\\.)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\\.[a-z]{2,6}$");
```

It validates correctly such names as: `google.com`, `mypage.mycompany.com`. But when subdomain name is of 3d+ lvl, then validation crashes. For example, `test.test2.test3.com` hasn't been validated yet.

What is wrong with this regexp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just allow the central pattern (`[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\\.`) to appear more than once :

```
var fqdnRegExp = new RegExp("^([a-z0-9]+\\.)?([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$");
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about it, hm.